# Adding google to IAM's Identity Providers OpenID Connect

Tags: google-plus, openid, openid-connect, amazon-cognito

This was hard to find so I'll add it here in case anyone needs it.

When adding google sign in as a cognito authentication provider for both Android and iOS I need to use the `OpenID` rather than `Google+`, but when adding in google as an `OpenID` I couldn't find the provider URL in [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The provider URL is hardcoded `accounts.google.com` for any credential you create, and add all the clientIDs under Audience.

To add google sign in to Cognito for both iOS and Android:

- Go to IAM -> Identity providers
- Create a provider
- Choose OpenID Connect
- In the provider url write `https://accounts.google.com`
- In Audience write one of the app's client_id that you can get from the [credentials console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?highlightClient=648776088645-t8utganfs873q1l6ffs92mdld1o3m7bo.apps.googleusercontent.com&project=my-guinea-pigs-1535628101387&folder&organizationId=1078701658705)

Go back to Cognito:

- Under authentication providers go to OpenID
- Select `accounts.google.com`

Comment: what option you selected while creating credentials in google console ? did you select Android or iOS or web ? I want it to work for both iOS and Android so which option should i select while creating credentials in google console?